# Swift - how to check for existing Core Data Store iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift, core-data

I'm working on an app that should have a starting window that will have an intro and then either a "Get Started" button if no existing core data store is found, and then if a store is present - it should have a "Continue Session" and "Start Over" buttons. Only problem I don't think my code for checking for a store is working - I'm putting this in the ViewController's viewDidLoad function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let defaultStorePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("LearnUSStateCapitals", ofType: "sqlite")
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if defaultStorePath == nil {
        println("can't find store")
        generateSCA()
    } else {
        println("store found...I think")
        continueButton.hidden = false
    }
```

So all I'm getting is "can't find store" - even after running the app a few times. I've navigated to `\Library\Developer\CoreSimulator\Devices\blahblah\data\Containers\Data\Application\blahblah\Documents` and do see my "LearnUSStateCapitals.sqlite" file there created at the time I first ran the app as is...

The reason I'm using `if defaultStorePath == nil` is because when I try `if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(defaultStorePath!)` I get `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` - why is this nil maybe the real question... thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you can see is in the Application Documents directory, which is different from the main bundle.  You can get a URL for the application documents directory with:

```
let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
let appDocsURL : NSURL = urls[urls.count - 1] as NSURL
let defaultStoreURL = appDocsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("LearnUSStateCapitals.sqlite")
```

then use:

```
if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(defaultStoreURL.path!) {
    println("can't find store")
    generateSCA()
} else {
    println("store found...I think")
    continueButton.hidden = false
}
```

Comment: Awesome - that worked - thanks so much
but does that mean my store is in the wrong place - I didn't use a "document" based app...didn't mean to anyway.

Comment: Your database is in the right place - the Documents directory is intended for app "documents" in the loosest of senses - almost all application data should go there (or subdirectories of it).  In fact the main bundle is read-only.